# usecontext variable resetting to 'undefined' when accessed through router navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have my app.js as below.

```
function App() {
    const [appUserCtx, setAppUserCtx] = useState();
    return (
        <AppUserContext.Provider value={{ appUserCtx, setAppUserCtx }}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path={['/admin/*', '/admin']} component={Admin} />
              /**Login */
                    <Route exact path={"/fmApp"} component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path={'/fmApp/customer/:id'} component={CustomerLogin} />
                    <Route path={'/fmApp/*'} component={FMApp} />
                    <Route exact path={Constants.ERROR_PAGE} component={ErrorPage} />
                </Switch>
            </Router >
        </AppUserContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

my AppUserContext

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AppUserContext = createContext({});

export default AppUserContext;
```

i wrapped AppUserContext under useAuth hook.

```
import { useContext, useDebugValue } from "react";
import AppUserContext from "./context/AppUserContext";

    const useAuth = () => {
       
        return useContext(AppUserContext);
    }
    
    export default useAuth;
```

i am setting the appUserCtx, down the line in a child component, `customerLogin.js`

```
 UserService.verifyLogin(axiosPrivate, appUser).
                then(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(response.data));
                    setAppUser(response.data);
                    setAppUserCtx(response.data);
                    setSubmitted(false);
                    props.history.push({ pathname: "/fmApp/dailySalesList" });
                }).catch(e => {
                    setSubmitted(false);
                    setModelVariant('error')
                    setMessage(e.response.data);
                    autoRef.current.setModelOpen(true);
                })
```

my appUserCtx is working on first flow, when i set in customerLogin.js, but when i navigate through nav bar under  `<Route path={'/fmApp/*'} component={FMApp} />` which has navigation menu and items, the appUserCtx becomes 'undefined' and i am not able to get context value which i have set in customerLogin.js page. not sure why my context value is getting reset, upon clicking on nav links.  i see useContext is global state which will not change until it is changed else where.

Edit :-

```
i am accessing through below nav navigation logic 

const FMApp = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const rediretToAmdin = () => {
    window.location.href = "/admin";
  }

  const {appUserCtx, setAppUserCtx} = useAuth();

 
  

  return (
      <div>
        <Navbar className='navbar'  variant="dark" expand="lg" sticky="top">
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home" className='p-0' style={{marginTop:'-12px'}}> <FMLogo height='30'/></Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <NavDropdown title="Stocks" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="/fmApp/fuelStockList">Fuel Stock</NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
              <div><Logout className="float-left" /></div>
            </Nav>
          {/* show admin access link only if user role is as admin enabled*/}
            {appUserCtx.userRoleMO?.isAdmin === 1 && <div> <StylesProvider injectFirst>  <Link className="adminLink" onClick={rediretToAmdin}>Go to admin</Link></StylesProvider></div>}
            <div> <ROHeader></ROHeader></div>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>

        <div className="container mt-3">
          <Switch>
            //stock
               <Route exact path={"/fmApp/fuelStockList"} component={FuelStockList} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default FMApp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [Context is cleared when I navigate to another page with the browser address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73346406/context-is-cleared-when-i-navigate-to-another-page-with-the-browser-address-bar).

useContext get initialized on browser navigation, hence i have use localStorage, since i need to persist context for entire user session.